# Power Automate multiple emails must arrive in order refresh dataset

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I am a little stumped on configuring a Power Automate flow.
Here’s what I am trying to do

1. Email A must arrive
2. Once Email A arrives, Email B and Email C must arrive
3. Once Email A, B, and C have all arrived then refresh PowerBi dataset.

The catch is that sometimes email C comes before email B and vice versa but email A always comes first no matter what.

I am fairly new to Power automate so if someone can explain what I need to do in detail that would be awesome.

Initially I had

- When an email arrives V3 and then a condition statement but the condition statement doesn’t work in this scenario

Comment: Assuming these three emails need to come in within a certain time frame? You would set the trigger for Email B or Email C. Then you would need to `Get emails (V3)` with the relevant parameters and then check if all three (A, B, C) are in that returned list. If so, do refresh.

Comment: Hi Sam, what action should I be using to check if all three are returned in the list? So from what I understand the first step should be 1. When an email arrives V3 (subject filter would be Email A) and then I get a little confused after that.. what should come next?

Answer (score 0):

Your first action or trigger action is the `When a new email arrives (V3)`. You want this to trigger for Email B or Email C.

Click on the `...` on the action and select `Settings`. At the bottom, under `Trigger Conditions`, click Add and enter:

```js
@or(
  contains(toLower(triggerOutputs()?['body/subject']), 'email B'),
  contains(toLower(triggerOutputs()?['body/subject']), 'email C')
)
```

For the next action, you'll want the `Get emails (V3)` action. In the `Search Query` enter the following:

```
subject:'Email A' OR subject:'Email B' OR subject:'Email C' AND 
received:@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-3),'yyyy-MM-dd')}..@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),1),'yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

Update the date range as needed (`-3` 3 days ago)

[image]

Then from the output of the above, you should be able to count the number of emails returned. If the length is 3 then trigger the next action (refresh).

Add a condition with (add as an expression):

```
length(outputs('Get_emails_(V3)')?['body/value'])
```

[image]

Comment: Should I be adding a condition? to count if 3 emails arrive? How would I do that?